# How to write a single line shell script with a while loop and if statement

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to figure out the syntax for having a while loop and an if statement that checks for more than one condition, in a single-line shell script.

Executing something like this...

```
i=2; while [ $i -le 10 ]; do if [ $i -ne 3 -a $i -ne 5 ] echo $i " not equal to 3 or 5"; else echo $i; i=`expr $i + 1`; done
```

...I get the error

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
```

On another hand if I remove the semicolon from between `...3 or 5"` and `else echo...`, and try something like this...

```
i=2; while [ $i -le 10 ]; do if [ $i -ne 3 -a $i -ne 5 ] echo $i " not equal to 3 or 5" else echo $i; i=`expr $i + 1`; done
```

...then I get the error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `done'
```

This is on an Ubuntu 14.04, in case it matters.

Am I perhaps missing some kind of a parenthesis somewhere, or is it something else?

Comment: The basic idea is to simply use the *end-of-line* delimiter `';'` wherever you would normally have a newline if you had written the script as a normally-formatted multi-line script. As noted below, you have missing `then` and `fi`'s as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
i=2; while [ $i -le 10 ]; do if [ $i -ne 3 -a $i -ne 5 ]; then echo $i " not equal to 3 or 5"; else echo $i; fi; i=`expr $i + 1`; done
```

and this should also work:

```
i=2; while [ $i -le 10 ]; do [ $i -ne 3 -a $i -ne 5 ] && echo "$i not equal to 3 or 5" || echo $i; i=$((i+1)); done
```

But I am not sure if it makes sense to write this in only one line

Comment: You're right — it makes no sense to write it all one one line.

Answer (score 4):

You still need a `then`, and a `fi`, and enough semicolons.

```
i=2; while [ $i -le 10 ]; do if [ $i -ne 3 -a $i -ne 5 ]; then echo "$i not equal to 3 or 5"; else echo $i; fi; i=$(expr $i + 1); done
```

The replacement of back-quotes `` `…` `` with `$(…)` is just a general good idea, not crucial to this discussion.

If written out conventionally on multiple lines (without semicolons), you'd have:

```
i=2
while [ $i -le 10 ]
do
    if [ $i -ne 3 -a $i -ne 5 ]
    then echo "$i not equal to 3 or 5"
    else echo $i
    fi
    i=$(expr $i + 1)
done
```

To convert that to a single line, you need a semicolon after each statement and condition:

```
i=2;
while [ $i -le 10 ];
do
    if [ $i -ne 3 -a $i -ne 5 ];
    then echo "$i not equal to 3 or 5";
    else echo $i;
    fi;
    i=$(expr $i + 1);
done
```

And now the white space (including newlines) can be replaced by single spaces on a single line.

And you could use `i=$(($i + 1))` or even (in Bash) `((i++))` in place of `expr`, which avoids the use of the external command `expr`; the shell does the arithmetic internally.

I don't think there is a good reason to flatten the script onto one line.

Answer (score 1):

Each `if` needs a `then` and `fi`:

```
i=2; while [ $i -le 10 ]; do if [ $i -ne 3 -a $i -ne 5 ] ; then echo $i " not equal to 3 or 5" ; else echo $i; i=`expr $i + 1`; fi ; done
```